# phpexcel Class PDO Connection Issue

Tags: php, pdo, phpexcel

I had a system. And i'm using phpexcel. You know mysql functions is deprecated in php 5.5. I decided to convert my system to PDO.

I converted whole my site. But there is a problem with phpexcel. Data is confused. And it is not readable. Result contains weird charachters.

For testing my script I commented all database operations. Only i left constants.

Here is my phpexcel script with only constants.

```
<?php   ob_start();
    session_start();

    /** Include PHPExcel */
    require_once 'includes/class/PHPExcel.php';
    require_once 'includes/class/class.product.php';    
    include_once 'includes/global.php';
    include_once 'includes/functions.php';
                  include_once 'locale.php';


$P = new Product();
// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Variables
$exceltype  = 'Fiyat Listesi';


// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', _('Stok Kodu'))
            ->setCellValue('B1', _('Ürün'))
            ->setCellValue('C1', _('Fiyatı'))
            ->setCellValue('D1', _('Min. Adet'))
            ->setCellValue('E1', _('Stok Durumu'));

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($exceltype);


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="pricelist.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
?>
```

This script output will be only single line A1-A5

But my output is like on screen-shot[image]

If i comment $P-> new Product and require_once('includes/class/class.product.php'). Output is ok.

I think that there is a confliction PDO and phpexcel class. Normally PDO works correctly in anywhere. Also phpexcel work correctly with mysql functions.

Here is my database class.

```
class Database {
    protected $_host           = "************";
    protected $_engine         = "************";
    protected $_dbuser         = "************";
    protected $_dbpassword     = "************";
    protected $_db             = "************";

    protected $_sql;
    protected $pdo;




    /* @desc This Function is Setting SQL Connection
     * @return SQL Connection
     * 
     */
    protected function getPdo()
    {
        if ($this->pdo === NULL) {
            try {

              $dsn = $this->_engine.':dbname='.$this->_db.';host='.$this->_host.';charset=utf8';

              $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->_dbuser, $this->_dbpassword);
              $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
              $this->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
              echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return $this->pdo;
    }




    /* @desc This Function is Preparing Sql Statement For Query
     * @return array Returns PDO Object Query
     * 
     */  
    public function query($sql)
    {
        return $this->_sql = $this->getPdo()->prepare($sql);
    }









    /* @desc This Function is for Binding Values into SQL Statements
     * @return Binded SQL Statements
     * 
     */
    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
        if (is_null($type)) {
          switch (true) {
            case is_int($value):
              $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
              break;
            case is_bool($value):
              $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
              break;
            case is_null($value):
              $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
              break;
            default:
              $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
          }
        }
        $this->_sql->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }








    /* @desc This Function Execute Query
     * @return SQL Execution
     * 
     */
    public function execute($values = NULL){
        return (!isset($values)) ? $this->_sql->execute() : $this->_sql->execute($values);
    }








    /* @desc This Function Execute Query and Fetch Multiple Result
     * @return array Returns Array of Table Rows. Array is multidimensional
     * 
     */
    public function queryResults(){
      $this->execute();
      return $this->_sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }






    /* @desc This Function Execute Query and Fetch Only Single Result
     * @return array Returns Array of Table Row. Array is not multidimensional.
     * 
     */
    public function queryResult(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->_sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }




    public function queryColumn($index = NULL){
        $index = (isset($index)) ? intval($index) : 0;
        $this->execute();
        return $this->_sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,$index);
//        $this->execute();
//        return $this->_sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    }







    /* @desc This Function Returns Effected Row Count during Update, Delete and Insert
     * @return int Returns Effected Row Count
     * 
     */
    public function effected(){
      return $this->_sql->rowCount();
    }






    /* @desc This Function Returns Effected Row Count during Update, Delete and Insert
     * @return int Returns Effected Row Count
     * 
     */
    public function rowCount(){
      return count($this->queryResults());
    }


    public function lastID(){
        return $this->_sql->lastInsertId();
    }

//    public function getColumn($index){
//        $index = (isset($index)) ? intval($index) : '';
//        $this->execute();
//        return $this->_sql->fetchColumn($index);
//    }
}
```

What should i do ?

**Edit :** I edited my code. And now i'm getting character encoding. Here is my new result. Some of results are ASCII. Some of results are UTF8. I couldn't understand the problem.

```
    Array
(
[2443] => Array
(
[stock_code] => 11100042
[title] => Dokuma Ã‡Ä±kartma
[min_quantity] => 50
[price] => 0.55
[stock_quantity] => 4300+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[2502] => Array
(
[stock_code] => 14140270
[title] => Sticker
[min_quantity] => 10
[price] => 1.4
[stock_quantity] => 20+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[100] => Array
(
[stock_code] => 14140285
[title] => KÃ¼Ã§Ã¼k Etiket
[min_quantity] => 25
[price] => 0.5
[stock_quantity] => 90+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[242] => Array
(
[stock_code] => 14140911
[title] => ArkasÄ± Kesik Semazen
[min_quantity] => 20
[price] => 1.5
[stock_quantity] => 30+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[2639] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B411140007
[title] => Magnet HalÄ± Tekli Simli
[min_quantity] => 35
[price] => 0.75
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1328] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B411140023
[title] => Telkari Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 2.25
[stock_quantity] => 1
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1329] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140014
[title] => Battal KaplumbaÄŸa Magnet
[min_quantity] => 20
[price] => 1.85
[stock_quantity] => 1100+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1081] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140015
[title] => BÃ¼yÃ¼k KaplumbaÄŸa Magnet
[min_quantity] => 20
[price] => 1.5
[stock_quantity] => 1000+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1082] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140016
[title] => KÃ¼Ã§Ã¼k KaplumbaÄŸa Magnet
[min_quantity] => 10
[price] => 1.25
[stock_quantity] => 340+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1080] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140017
[title] => Renkli KaplumbaÄŸa Magnet
[min_quantity] => 10
[price] => 1.75
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1079] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140018
[title] => Plastik Ã‡arÄ±k Magnet
[min_quantity] => 10
[price] => 1.25
[stock_quantity] => 360
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[3727] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140019
[title] => Renkli Terlik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 20
[price] => 1.5
[stock_quantity] => 710
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[3667] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140020
[title] => Hamur Balon Magnet
[min_quantity] => 20
[price] => 1.35
[stock_quantity] => 2400+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[3729] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140024
[title] => Hamur YÄ±ldÄ±z Magnet
[min_quantity] => 20
[price] => 1.5
[stock_quantity] => 670
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[789] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140051
[title] => PaÅŸabahÃ§e Magnet
[min_quantity] => 40
[price] => 0.65
[stock_quantity] => 200+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1960] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140055
[title] => AhÅŸap Havan Magnet
[min_quantity] => 10
[price] => 1.15
[stock_quantity] => 240+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1747] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140063
[title] => Oval AÃ§acak Magnet
[min_quantity] => 20
[price] => 1.5
[stock_quantity] => 170+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1330] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140064
[title] => Damla Magnet
[min_quantity] => 20
[price] => 1.25
[stock_quantity] => 1600+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1163] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140065
[title] => AÃ§acak Magnet
[min_quantity] => 5
[price] => 2.25
[stock_quantity] => -10+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[791] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140066
[title] => Keskin Magnet
[min_quantity] => 12
[price] => 1.35
[stock_quantity] => 3600+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1838] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140067
[title] => Keskin Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 12
[price] => 1
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[792] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140068
[title] => Makrome Magnet
[min_quantity] => 20
[price] => 1.2
[stock_quantity] => 1200+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1331] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140069
[title] => Deve Magnet
[min_quantity] => 20
[price] => 1.1
[stock_quantity] => 100+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1332] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140070
[title] => Panaromik Damla Magnet
[min_quantity] => 10
[price] => 2.25
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[793] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140071
[title] => Bebek Magnet
[min_quantity] => 48
[price] => 1
[stock_quantity] => 3800+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[2640] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140072
[title] => Cam Magnet
[min_quantity] => 10
[price] => 3
[stock_quantity] => 50
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1963] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140074
[title] => Cam BuzdolabÄ± Magnet
[min_quantity] => 50
[price] => 1
[stock_quantity] => 60
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[3513] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140075
[title] => Bob Marley Magnet
[min_quantity] => 24
[price] => 1.85
[stock_quantity] => 450+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[3514] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140076
[title] => Erotik Bob  Magnet
[min_quantity] => 24
[price] => 2
[stock_quantity] => 480
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[3177] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140100
[title] => YÄ±ldÄ±z Magnet
[min_quantity] => 24
[price] => 1.5
[stock_quantity] => 710+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[3178] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140101
[title] => Terlik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 24
[price] => 1.6
[stock_quantity] => 100+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[3636] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140102
[title] => Balon Magnet
[min_quantity] => 12
[price] => 1.25
[stock_quantity] => 30+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[796] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140321
[title] => Resimli Magnet
[min_quantity] => 20
[price] => 0.5
[stock_quantity] => 450+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[799] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140467
[title] => ÃœzÃ¼mlÃ¼ Magnet
[min_quantity] => 10
[price] => 2.25
[stock_quantity] => 40
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[800] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140469
[title] => Oval Kapadokya Magnet
[min_quantity] => 10
[price] => 1.4
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[802] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140554
[title] => Horozlu Magnet
[min_quantity] => 6
[price] => 2
[stock_quantity] => 5+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[2478] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140560
[title] => 230416 Magnet
[min_quantity] => 24
[price] => 1.25
[stock_quantity] => 9300+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[2479] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140561
[title] => 1440020 AÃ§acak Magnet
[min_quantity] => 24
[price] => 1.5
[stock_quantity] => 4100+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[3171] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140562
[title] => Renkli KarÄ±ÅŸÄ±k Magnet
[min_quantity] => 48
[price] => 1.25
[stock_quantity] => 90+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[3172] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140563
[title] => Renkli AÃ§acak Magnet
[min_quantity] => 28
[price] => 2.5
[stock_quantity] => 80+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[3173] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140564
[title] => Renkli Dereceli Magnet
[min_quantity] => 28
[price] => 1.85
[stock_quantity] => 50+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[803] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140797
[title] => Kristal Papatya Magnet
[min_quantity] => 25
[price] => 1.5
[stock_quantity] => 980+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[804] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140802
[title] => KarÄ±ÅŸÄ±k Hayvan Magnet
[min_quantity] => 50
[price] => 1.7
[stock_quantity] => 1800+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[805] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140820
[title] => Polyester KabartmalÄ± Magnet
[min_quantity] => 60
[price] => 1.75
[stock_quantity] => 240+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1650] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140855
[title] => BÃ¼yÃ¼k KuÅŸadasÄ± Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 170
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1084] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140860
[title] => BÃ¼yÃ¼k Bergama Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 170
[stock_quantity] => 1
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1086] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140861
[title] => BÃ¼yÃ¼k Efes Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 170
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1088] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140862
[title] => BÃ¼yÃ¼k Truva Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 170
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1192] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140863
[title] => BÃ¼yÃ¼k KapÄ± No Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 170
[stock_quantity] => 4
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1193] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140864
[title] => BÃ¼yÃ¼k Semazen Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 170
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1194] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140865
[title] => BÃ¼yÃ¼k Kilim Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 170
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1195] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140866
[title] => BÃ¼yÃ¼k Ã‡ini Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 170
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1087] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140867
[title] => BÃ¼yÃ¼k Pamukkale Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 170
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1085] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140868
[title] => BÃ¼yÃ¼k Kapadokya Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 170
[stock_quantity] => 10+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1544] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140869
[title] => BÃ¼yÃ¼k Cami Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 170
[stock_quantity] => 2
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1729] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140870
[title] => BÃ¼yÃ¼k Lale Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 170
[stock_quantity] => 4
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1083] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140877
[title] => BÃ¼yÃ¼k Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 1.6
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[807] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140883
[title] => Ä°ÅŸlemeli Magnet KarÄ±ÅŸÄ±k
[min_quantity] => 20
[price] => 1.5
[stock_quantity] => 15600+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[809] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140904
[title] => AhÅŸap Magnet
[min_quantity] => 20
[price] => 1.65
[stock_quantity] => 740+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[810] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140905
[title] => DÃ¼nya 3 Boyutlu Magnet
[min_quantity] => 20
[price] => 0.9
[stock_quantity] => 3000
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1334] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140906
[title] => Tabak Magnet
[min_quantity] => 20
[price] => 0.75
[stock_quantity] => 280+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[812] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140910
[title] => PeribacalÄ± Magnet
[min_quantity] => 20
[price] => 1.1
[stock_quantity] => 170+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1335] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140915
[title] => Mini EÅŸek Magnet
[min_quantity] => 20
[price] => 1.3
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1196] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140922
[title] => Kilim Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 2
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 5+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1197] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140923
[title] => Ä°kon Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 2
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 10+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1198] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140924
[title] => Kapadokya Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1199] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140925
[title] => Ayet Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 2
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 5+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1200] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140926
[title] => Semazen Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 2
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 10+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1201] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140927
[title] => Efes Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 2
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 10+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1202] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140928
[title] => Nazar Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 2
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 2
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1203] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140929
[title] => Bayrak Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 2
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 2
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1204] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140930
[title] => Mudurnu Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1205] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140931
[title] => Nasreddin Hoca Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 2
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 10+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1206] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140932
[title] => Aspendos Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1207] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140933
[title] => Åžirince Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1208] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140934
[title] => Manavgat Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1209] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140935
[title] => Pamukkale Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 2
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 2
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1210] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140936
[title] => Nemrut Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1211] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140937
[title] => Abant GÃ¶lÃ¼ Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1212] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140938
[title] => Safranbolu Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1213] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140939
[title] => Ã‡ini Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 2
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 10+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1545] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140940
[title] => Tepesidelikhan Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1651] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140941
[title] => KuÅŸadasÄ± Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 2
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 10+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1652] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140942
[title] => AyvalÄ±k Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1653] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140943
[title] => Bergama Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 2
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 2
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1730] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140944
[title] => Didim Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1731] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140945
[title] => GravÃ¼r Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1732] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140946
[title] => MinyatÃ¼r Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 1
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1852] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140947
[title] => KaÅŸ Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[1853] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140948
[title] => Dalyan Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 1
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1875] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140951
[title] => GÃ¶lcÃ¼k Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 2
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 5+
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[3547] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140962
[title] => UzungÃ¶l Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 2
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[3548] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140963
[title] => Hz. Ali Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 4
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 5+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[3736] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140964
[title] => Alanya Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 2
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[3737] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140965
[title] => Side Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 2
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[3738] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140966
[title] => Ayder YaylasÄ± Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 2
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[3740] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B414140968
[title] => OsmanlÄ± ArmasÄ± Seramik Magnet
[min_quantity] => 2
[price] => 85
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => UTF-8
)
[815] => Array
(
[stock_code] => B417170015
[title] => Magnet Kartpostal
[min_quantity] => 48
[price] => 0.85
[stock_quantity] => 1800+
[encoding] => ASCII
)
[1569] => Array
(
[stock_code] => KR060510001
[title] => Magnet (mgn01)
[min_quantity] => 20
[price] => 1.5
[stock_quantity] => 0
[encoding] => ASCII
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in a text editor and look for any leading/trailing whitespace characters/BOM header or plaintext error messages in the file that might be coming from your new database class:

e.g.

if your getPdo() fails to connect, you echo a message

```
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
```

any output, including such error messages, will inject that text into the `php://output` stream and corrupt the generated file

Even something a simple as a new line after the closing `?>` can add that newline to the output stream

Comment: i edited my code. and now i'm getting encoding of title value. Some of them are ASCII. Some of them are UTF-8.